# Making a CSS button: positioning the text

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to make a rudimentary css button.

I'm encountering errors while trying to position the text vertically and horizontally centered within the button. I have this following html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #button
    {
      background:lightblue;
      border-radius: 30px;
      width: 15em;
      height: 3em;
      position:relative;
    }
    h1 {
      vertical-align: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Making a button...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="button"><h1>Click Me</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle for this question: http://jsfiddle.net/CRpvr/

I was told there was a workaround using `line-height: 100%`, but if I need more than one line, this doesnt work very well. What is the most idiomatic and proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: actually, it's not a 'button' .. it's a divider

Comment: It depends what browser you're writing this for. This doesn't work in IE, but in Chrome/FireFox adding a `padding-top: 5px` to your h1 CSS will align it the way you want.

Comment: You shouldn't use an `<h1>` tag just to change the style of something. They're intended to be used for different headings on a page- use a `<span>` and style that instead. Additionally, your button should probably be a `class="button"` instead of an `id`- you'll want more than one button, won't you? :)

Comment: `center` is not a proper value for `vertical-align`. You want:
`vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle` might work for you.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CRpvr/7/

Answer (score 10):

Simply change "height" within your button ID to "line-height". I checked this and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me when the other, higher-voted answers did not. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

just add some padding to it:

```
padding:0.5em
```

sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/cr9ef/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just set a padding on your id="button" rather than a height, like so:

```
#button
{
  background:lightblue;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 15em;
  padding:1em;
  position:relative;
}
```

This will create a top and bottom padding on the div and spread the top and bottom equal distances away from your wording.  This also eliminates the need for your vertical align attribute in the h1 CSS tag.

Comment: or add this : line-height:3em; vertical-align:middle;

Comment: I find this method to be much less responsive.  This creates a permanently fixed button.  By simply adding a padding, changes to your h1 font size will not require you to also change line height.

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height:3em;` to the `#button` style.  Make the value of it the same as the height.  If you need two lines, make it half the height, and so on.  Just make sure to make your `font-size` smaller the more lines you have.

If you want to keep the `font-size` the same, you can make the button taller by adjusting the height to the amount of lines you have.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy6f9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just make your container the right height, then vertically align within it this way ::

```
<style type="text/css">
    #button
    {
      background:lightblue;
      border-radius: 30px;
      width: 15em;
      height: 3em;
      line-height: 3em;  /*  <-- this was it ! */
      vertical-align: middle;
      position:relative;
    }
    h1 {
      vertical-align: middle;
      /*vertical-align: center;*/ /* w.t.f? */
      text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
```

PS, validate your CSS : vertical-align:center is not correct ???